# Line of code is giving me an error "Error in render: "RangeError: Invalid array length"", however, the line still does what it's meant to do

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The line of code is supposed to round a float number and then display stars equal to that rating number. Strangely, the line of code does what is it meant to do, however, it also gives me an error `Error in render: "RangeError: Invalid array length"`

```
<p>Rating: <i v-for='n in Math.round(sight.rating)' class="rating-stars fas fa-star"></i></p>
```

If I replace Math.round(sight.rating) with an actual integer, I don't get the error. If I replace it with a float number, I get the error so I assume it's the float number's fault. However, if I'm not mistaken Math.round(sight.rating) should return an int, right?

Sight object:

```
{
  "address_components": [
    {
      "long_name": "3",
      "short_name": "3",
      "types": [
        "premise"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "10",
      "short_name": "10",
      "types": [
        "sublocality_level_4",
        "sublocality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "2-chōme",
      "short_name": "2-chōme",
      "types": [
        "sublocality_level_3",
        "sublocality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Toranomon",
      "short_name": "Toranomon",
      "types": [
        "sublocality_level_2",
        "sublocality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Minato City",
      "short_name": "Minato City",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Tōkyō-to",
      "short_name": "Tōkyō-to",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Japan",
      "short_name": "JP",
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "105-0001",
      "short_name": "105-0001",
      "types": [
        "postal_code"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "adr_address": "<span class=\"street-address\">2-chōme-10-3 Toranomon, Minato City</span>, <span class=\"region\">Tōkyō-to</span> <span class=\"postal-code\">105-0001</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">Japan</span>",
  "formatted_address": "2-chōme-10-3 Toranomon, Minato City, Tōkyō-to 105-0001, Japan",
  "formatted_phone_number": "03-3583-0781",
  "geometry": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 35.6670115,
      "lng": 139.7433683
    },
    "viewport": {
      "northeast": {
        "lat": 35.6683604802915,
        "lng": 139.7447172802915
      },
      "southwest": {
        "lat": 35.6656625197085,
        "lng": 139.7420193197085
      }
    }
  },
  "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/museum-71.png",
  "id": "2398d5f2d109e85f2d4d1f3b76a0ff0c64d7b685",
  "international_phone_number": "+81 3-3583-0781",
  "name": "Okura Museum of Art (Okura Shukokan)",
  "photos": [
    {
      "height": 3080,
      "html_attributions": [
        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101996694022263068076/photos\">Pene Clitoride</a>"
      ],
      "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAABc3LWvw8Z9y50ailegR1cxwNYsdwDKNlqYc3p0x23GJE80IeTjWcegp7yRHdAKXQ3RgOV4NAkwdAoawJ-rhsiIqOjbby44hGzhxVD35VYfSpU6lSfcZLHUKrcoiSlDFEhCMV_EWgEZ3njumqeYTpOa0GhRRZ96km2C-Pru-Tk_9TpBQDI1PeQ",
      "width": 5472
    },
    {
      "height": 5472,
      "html_attributions": [
        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110122217716740147589/photos\">Maria Colonna</a>"
      ],
      "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAJ36EEeDQxR3aDicXodZ4VoBKQFfVEUKY_r_2tumrrTvZAsrZFypLG0trx4RSPR18f9dMHeF8XePTkEzntwf8aIg1PDS994jP6447B4MCTH9ILDztS3GvPCYT94VKVIYwEhA98am5HDQ9GYDu4FQioNizGhR3hivoKGbC61--_Lp3Wcdaf8uvIg",
      "width": 3080
    }
  ],
  "place_id": "ChIJC5-nF5CLGGAR9M3JUrPsBj8",
  "plus_code": {
    "compound_code": "MP8V+R8 Tokyo, Japan",
    "global_code": "8Q7XMP8V+R8"
  },
  "rating": 2.7,
  "reference": "ChIJC5-nF5CLGGAR9M3JUrPsBj8",
  "reviews": [
    {
      "author_name": "作田知樹",
      "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/112232926057787995756/reviews",
      "language": "en",
      "profile_photo_url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-MSSR5BJRciM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rfxQ43JGCXYylp5GJBrww3TdvDEUQ/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4/photo.jpg",
      "rating": 3,
      "relative_time_description": "a year ago",
      "text": "Closed until 2019.",
      "time": 1520830709
    },
    {
      "author_name": "hillary c",
      "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/111913221922184324953/reviews",
      "language": "en",
      "profile_photo_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-3c8oNLLlw-4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADE/tFcg16xSZXw/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba3/photo.jpg",
      "rating": 2,
      "relative_time_description": "3 years ago",
      "text": "Closed for renovations for four years, starting in April of 2015",
      "time": 1431984440
    },
    {
      "author_name": "おおほりまこと",
      "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/116946076996856905143/reviews",
      "language": "ja",
      "profile_photo_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-FyN5KLlV37I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rdybVohcNv6MAr8pOt-2tYysm1r8g/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba6/photo.jpg",
      "rating": 4,
      "relative_time_description": "2 months ago",
      "text": "休館中、建物は国の重要文化財です。",
      "time": 1549283359
    },
    {
      "author_name": "chun li lin",
      "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/105258621249998744671/reviews",
      "language": "zh",
      "profile_photo_url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-3j1Np8bGGGA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3reG0rVSFGsxyhQQcWlXxRapQAc5KA/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4/photo.jpg",
      "rating": 4,
      "relative_time_description": "a year ago",
      "text": "整修中",
      "time": 1521062392
    },
    {
      "author_name": "Yoshio Akiyama",
      "author_url": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/109720304741660602673/reviews",
      "profile_photo_url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-KLvOxW89_gc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rdznxqHNfDH5dkIZemt90WBpJZV-w/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
      "rating": 1,
      "relative_time_description": "3 months ago",
      "text": "",
      "time": 1547060834
    }
  ],
  "scope": "GOOGLE",
  "types": [
    "museum",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
  ],
  "url": "https://maps.google.com/?cid=4541577529181982196",
  "user_ratings_total": 11,
  "utc_offset": 540,
  "vicinity": "2 Chome-10-3 Toranomon, Minato City",
  "website": "http://www.shukokan.org/"
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use ```Math.round(Number(sight.rating))``` ?

Comment: Error still persists

Comment: I could not reproduce it with: https://jsfiddle.net/goz173t6/

Comment: Cant reproduce your error. Can you post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: can you share the data inside "sight" variable.

Comment: Added the data inside "sight". @RolandStarke Your code indeed does not reproduce the error. Weird thing is that the code is working and I'm seeing the stars, however, getting the error in the console is no bueno even if the code is working.

Comment: Another thing I just found out is that if I replace sight.rating with a hard coded float, I don't get the error either.

Comment: I just added a answer. Let me know if its works for you or not. Thanks

Comment: `"rating": 2.7,` here, `sight.rating` is a float / int (type cast), why you are looping on it?

Comment: Well I'm trying to round it to an int and then display number of stars equal to the rounded rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when an array is constructed with a non-positive-integer number, e.g:

```
new Array(3.14)
new Array(-1)
new Array(NaN)
new Array(Infinity)
```

Perhaps `Math.round(sight.rating)` is returning NaN? This can happen if `sight.rating` is `undefined`.

Hold off rendering the rating until `sight.rating` has a value to avoid this error:

```
<!-- Don't render the rating at all -->
<p v-if="sight.rating != null">
  Rating: <i v-for='n in Math.round(sight.rating)' class="rating-stars fas fa-star"></i>
</p>

<!-- Or render a 0-rating. Whatever works for you. -->
<p>
  Rating: <i v-for='n in Math.round(sight.rating || 0)' class="rating-stars fas fa-star"></i>
</p>
```

Comment: Could this have something to do with the fact that the sight variable is empty by default and the sight information is assigned to it after a GET request which is executed on mounted() of component?

Comment: Yes, that would mean `sight.rating` would be `undefined` during the render.

Comment: Yes this seemed to be the issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Rating:

I think you need to check if `rating` is available in all the index items of the array or not.

If rating is not available you need to put some condition there,

else you can try below code. Hope it will work.

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>Rating: <span v-for='n in Math.round(sight.rating || 1)'>⭐</span></p>
</div>
```

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejysfad3/1/) here
Thanks